# Shrink and zoom not working mobile device Chrome

Tags: html, meta-tags

I tried to shrink and zoom in Chrome it from a mobile browser (I tried it on Chrome browser on an Android and iPhone).
But it's not working.

```
<meta name=“viewport” content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5, maximum-scale=12.0, minimum-scale=.25, user-scalable=yes"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is the problem.
But, I think that you are using different quptation marks for the name property `“”` instead of `""`.
You can also delete the `user-scalable=yes` as it is the default.
At last, make sure that you declare your page as HTML5 with the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration.
Try using this code instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.5, maximum-scale=12.0, minimum-scale=.25"/>
<title>Your Title</title>
</head>

<body>
Your CONTENT
</body>

</html>
```